# click on submit key without ID?

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to test my code and there is a submit button that I have to click, BUT this submit button get dynamic id name. how can I click on this key with my selenium script without using an ID.

```
<td>
  <button type="submit" value="Allow All" class="btn btnC bglb mfss touchable" 
   id="xhp647364382646" role="button" data-meta="0_3" 
   data-sigil="extra-perms-button blocking-touchable"> Allow All </button>
</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

WebElement has a **submit** method. If you can get a webelement which is inside the form, then you can call webelement.submit(). This is in JAVA. You should be having something similar in ruby

> void submit()
>
> If this current element is a form, or an element within
> a form, then this will be submitted to the remote server. If this
> causes the current page to change, then this method will block until
> the new page is loaded. Throws: NoSuchElementException - If the given
> element is not within a form

Comment: how about if there are two submit on the form !?

Comment: Can you post HTML of that form - atleast the line for both submit buttons?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what all of your code looks like and where the other submit button is but if there are 2 submit buttons, you could try doing

`buttons = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("button[type='submit']")`

or something similar, that will return all the submit buttons. Notice `elements` is plural in the function name, there is also one that is `find_element_by_css_selector`(unpluralized). Then, you can access the button you want by using

`buttons[0]`

then you could submit by

`buttons[0].click()`